# I got Exception in handleDisplayableEvent. Reason: LinkageError

Tags: java, java-me, j2mepolish

Hey Hi Friends I got exception in my method... 
please help me error like that

```
Exception in handleDisplayableEvent. Reason: LinkageError  source is : com.ui.PreviewPageUI@38f838f8
```

code of my method here it reaches to method but after that it shows above exception... see code...

```
private void getPreviewData(final String cat) {
    System.out.println("I am in privew data:"+cat);
    Thread th = new Thread() {
           public void run() {
            try {
                if (cat.equals("VD")) {
                    if (videoHastable == null || videoHastable.isEmpty()) {
                        initializeWaiting();
                        //ParseData parseData = new ParseData();
                       // String url = "http://122.170.122.186/web/papilon1.jsp?phonetype=" + Midlet.PHONE_TYPE + "&cat=VD";
                        //videoHastable = parseData.connectAndPTheUrl(url);
                        ParseUrl parsedata=new ParseUrl();
                        json=new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            json.put("phonetype",Midlet.PHONE_TYPE);
                            json.put("cat","VD");
                        } catch (JSONException ex) {
                            System.out.println("jsException:"+ex.toString());
                        }
                        String url="http://localhost:8084/MagicWeb/pappilon1?json="+json.toString();

                        videoHastable =parsedata.coonectHttp(url,cat);
                        circularLoading = false;
                    }
                    if (videoHastable != null) {
                        Midlet.display.setCurrent(new WallPapersCanvas(2, "VIDEOS", videoHastable));
                    } else {
                        initializeError("MESSAGE", "COULD NOT POPULATE DATA FROM THE SERVER", MAIN_CATEGORIES);
                    }
                } else if (cat.equals("WP")) {
                    System.out.println("I am in wallpaper");
                    if (wallHastable == null || wallHastable.isEmpty()) {
                        initializeWaiting();
                        /*ParseData parseData = new ParseData();
                        String url = "http://122.170.122.186/web/papilon1.jsp?phonetype=" + Midlet.PHONE_TYPE + "&cat=WP";
                        wallHastable = parseData.connectAndPTheUrl(url);*/
                        ParseUrl parsedata=new ParseUrl();
                        json=new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            json.put("phonetype",Midlet.PHONE_TYPE);
                            json.put("cat","WP");
                        }catch(JSONException e){
                            System.out.println("json excep:"+e.toString());
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            System.out.println("error in wp getpriview:"+e.toString());
                        }
                        String url="http://localhost:8084/MagicWeb/pappilon1?json="+json.toString();
                        System.out.println("I am in wallpaper getpreiview");
                        wallHastable =parsedata.coonectHttp(url,cat);
                        circularLoading = false;
                    }
                    if (wallHastable != null) {
                        Midlet.display.setCurrent(new WallPapersCanvas(2, "WALLPAPERS", wallHastable));
                    } else {
                        initializeError("MESSAGE", "COULD NOT POPULATE DATA FROM THE SERVER", MAIN_CATEGORIES);
                    }
                } else if (cat.equals("GM")) {
                    if (gamesHastable == null || gamesHastable.isEmpty()) {
                        initializeWaiting();
                        /*ParseData parseData = new ParseData();
                        String url = "http://122.170.122.186/web/papilon1.jsp?phonetype=" + Midlet.PHONE_TYPE + "&cat=GM";
                        gamesHastable = parseData.connectAndPTheUrl(url);*/
                        ParseUrl parsedata=new ParseUrl();
                        json=new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            json.put("phonetype",Midlet.PHONE_TYPE);
                            json.put("cat","GM");
                        } catch (JSONException ex) {
                            System.out.println(ex.toString());
                        }
                        String url="http://localhost:8084/MagicWeb/pappilon1?json="+json.toString();
                        gamesHastable =parsedata.coonectHttp(url,cat);
                        circularLoading = false;
                    }
                    if (gamesHastable != null) {
                        Midlet.display.setCurrent(new WallPapersCanvas(2, "GAMES", gamesHastable));
                    } else {
                        initializeError("MESSAGE", "COULD NOT POPULATE DATA FROM THE SERVER", MAIN_CATEGORIES);
                    }
                } else if (cat.equals("TH")) {
                    if (themesHastable == null || themesHastable.isEmpty()) {
                        initializeWaiting();
                        /*ParseData parseData = new ParseData();
                        String url = "http://122.170.122.186/web/papilon1.jsp?phonetype=" + Midlet.PHONE_TYPE + "&cat=TH";
                        themesHastable = parseData.connectAndPTheUrl(url);*/
                        ParseUrl parsedata=new ParseUrl();
                        json=new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            json.put("phonetype",Midlet.PHONE_TYPE);
                            json.put("cat","TH");
                        } catch (JSONException ex) {
                            System.out.println(ex.toString());
                        }
                        String url="http://localhost:8084/MagicWeb/pappilon1?json="+json.toString();
                        themesHastable =parsedata.coonectHttp(url,cat);
                        circularLoading = false;
                    }
                    if (themesHastable != null) {
                        Midlet.display.setCurrent(new WallPapersCanvas(2, "THEMES", themesHastable));
                    } else {
                        initializeError("MESSAGE", "COULD NOT POPULATE DATA FROM THE SERVER", MAIN_CATEGORIES);
                    }
                } else if (cat.equals("AN")) {
                    if (animateHastable == null || animateHastable.isEmpty()) {
                        initializeWaiting();
                        /*ParseData parseData = new ParseData();
                        String url = "http://122.170.122.186/web/papilon1.jsp?phonetype=" + Midlet.PHONE_TYPE + "&cat=AN";
                        animateHastable = parseData.connectAndPTheUrl(url);*/
                        ParseUrl parsedata=new ParseUrl();
                        json=new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            json.put("phonetype",Midlet.PHONE_TYPE);
                            json.put("cat","AN");
                        } catch (JSONException ex) {
                            System.out.println(ex.toString());
                        }
                        String url="http://localhost:8084/MagicWeb/pappilon1?json="+json.toString();
                        animateHastable =parsedata.coonectHttp(url,cat);
                        circularLoading = false;
                    }
                    if (animateHastable != null) {
                        Midlet.display.setCurrent(new WallPapersCanvas(2, "ANIMATIONS", animateHastable));
                    } else {
                        initializeError("MESSAGE", "COULD NOT POPULATE DATA FROM THE SERVER", MAIN_CATEGORIES);
                    }
                } else if (cat.equals("FS")) {
                    if (freeHastable == null || freeHastable.isEmpty()) {
                        initializeWaiting();
                        /*ParseData parseData = new ParseData();
                        String url = "http://122.170.122.186/disney/papilonfree.jsp?phonetype=" + Midlet.PHONE_TYPE;
                        freeHastable = parseData.connectAndPTheUrl(url);*/
                        ParseUrl parsedata=new ParseUrl();
                        json=new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            json.put("phonetype",Midlet.PHONE_TYPE);
                            json.put("cat","FS");
                        } catch (JSONException ex) {
                            System.out.println(ex.toString());
                        }
                        String url="http://localhost:8084/MagicWeb/pappilon1?json="+json.toString();
                        freeHastable =parsedata.coonectHttp(url,cat);
                        circularLoading = false;
                    }
                    if (freeHastable != null) {
                        Midlet.display.setCurrent(new WallPapersCanvas(2, "FREE GIFTS", freeHastable));
                    } else {
                        initializeError("MESSAGE", "COULD NOT POPULATE DATA FROM THE SERVER", MAIN_CATEGORIES);
                    }
                } else {
                    initializeError("MESSAGE", "CATEGORY NAME DOES NOT EXIST", MAIN_CATEGORIES);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error @ getPreviewData");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    System.out.println("Thread not started");
    try{
        th.start();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("thread th:"+e.toString());
    }
}
```

please help me Thanks....

Comment: First, please print your whole exceptions stack traces (with `ex.printStackTrace()`, not only the `toString()` result.

Comment: Second, what does that have to do with Javadoc? Which frameworks are you using here?

Comment: I have used Netbean & S60 Emulator it reaches to this line after that it got an error System.out.println("I am in privew data:"+cat);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the description of LinkageError:

> Subclasses of LinkageError indicate that a class has some dependency on another class; however, the latter class has incompatibly changed after the compilation of the former class.

Something has happened to one of your classes. Perhaps you need to recompile them, or reverify them.

Comment: I have recompiled all files but didn't get solution

Comment: But who defines `com.ui.PreviewPage`? That's the class that's giving you problems.